# Preventing soap from slipping in washbasin

Tags: bathroom

I have a wash basin with little space for keeping soap(wall and wash basin corner intersection). I can place soap there but problem is the surface there is  very smooth. After washing hands with soap, soap becomes wet. And this makes the smooth surface slippery. Soap slides to the centre of basin where drain is.

It feels kinda dirty to see the soap used for cleaning hands has become a mess. Because we clean hands, spit, etc.

Any method to prevent soap from sliding into washbasin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When done with the soap, upon placing it beside the sink, push down on it. It will then stick where placed and stay there.

Comment: I wanted to accept your answer. Only problem is that this method will greatly deform the soap

Comment: You don't have to push down very hard! maybe wiggle it a bit, too.

Comment: OK. I will try that now.

Comment: Yeah it is sticking. I will need to remove the plastic box that I tied to tap p firmly.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a hack unless you use any old dish you have available, but either use a soap dish (any small dish will do, but bear in mind the dish gets water in and the soap gets even soggier) or get hold of a soap saver - this is an oval or round, double sided suction pad (available on Amazon) - they stick to the sink and your soap can be stuck to the top if you press it hard enough after use. Other versions have a more needlelike arrangement on top to rest the soap on. You'd need to clean the soap saver regularly, but your soap will be drier on one of these than in a soap dish.

Alternatively, ditch the bar of soap and  use liquid soap in a dispenser - no mess, no gunk.

Comment: That was my first thought. Only thing is the dish I have is little big than required (does not fit there ; tap collides ).

Comment: Well I did not know about double sided suction pad. I will check out immediately. Thanks for that piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

Relatives of mine have a cool system. They have what looks like the screw cap on the top of a soda bottle, except it's not threaded, and it's made of magnetic metal.  They shove the open end of that into a bar of hand soap.  Then they have a magnet affixed to their sink that the metal bit (and the soap) sticks to. When the soap gets too small, they scoop the remaining soap out of the metal "cap" and shove it into another bar.

Or you could get one of the soap holders in the picture below that doesn't hold water so the soap doesn't become "water logged".  You can glue or screw the soap holder to the little shelf you have so it doesn't fall off.  If it ever does need to be cleaned, use a kitchen scrub brush while pouring water on top of it.  (Sorry I couldn't find a better picture!)
[image: soap holder]

Answer (score 1):

Clean thoroughly the area where you want to leave the soap.  When it's clean (and absolutely dry) take a cocktail stick and put tiny dots of white uPVC sealant on the shelved area. (Don't try to apply it direct from the sealant gun they'll be much too big and they'll be visible.) The dots give friction which hold the soap from slipping.

You can flatten the dots very carefully with a wetted finger.

Leave to dry overnight. I did this to my washbasin several months ago and to my surprise the dots are still there despite the usual regular cleaning routine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a plastic box with size similar to the soap and make several holes on the bottom to prevent filling it with water. I sometimes use a box of ice-cream or cheese which here are strong enough and not easy to break.

Then you can fix this plastic box with some glue, sanitary silicon or tie it for something with some wire.

Comment: Well this solved my difficulty. I tied a plastic box around tap. And I am able to put soap within it without soap falling . but I still wonder for how much time the string will be tight? (I mean string will become loose by few days afterall)

Answer (score 0):

Use a butter dish. It may be inconvenient, but you can stop the soap from slipping if it's big enough!